# Are there any recipes involving dinosaurs I could try?

Tags: dinosaurs

I know, I know, I love dinosaurs, but I have been curious of what the ancient chicken ancestors tasted like. are there any recipes I could try, and what ingredients would I need?

Comment: As a starting point you might like the question [How to butcher your dragon?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/63016/how-to-butcher-your-dragon), though the focus is a bit different.

Comment: Judging by evolutionary relationship, chicken tastes like dinosaur...

Comment: This is a site to help people build consistent fictional worlds, for games or novels or the like. I don't see how we can handle a counterfactual question such as yours without much more input on your story.

Comment: thank you for the comments, I will try to improve this as best I can, so thank you for the input.

Comment: Dinosauria is a big order.

Comment: I remember for Trexgiving we used to have stuffed T-Rex...

Comment: T-Rex sauteed in a light Unicorn sauce is reputed to be quite savory.

Comment: your question has issues, downvoting and closing it has nothing to do with hate. Also, editing it to complain about it will not help getting less downvotes or to reopen the question.

Comment: Kentucky Fried Chicken is a pretty common way to eat dinosaur. McNuggets is an alternative fast food recipe.

Comment: Any poultry recipe is a dinosaur recipe.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that this is a humourous way of ask "how edible would a dinosaur's flesh be?", that being the case the answer is something on the order of: we have no concrete idea but for the smaller ones that you could spit roast Emu or Ostrich meat *might* be a good starting point, or they might all have produced Allopumiliotoxins like Poison Dart Frogs and you'd drop dead if you got too close to the cook fire.

Comment: that is a pretty good answer, and yes, that is kind of what i'm asking. I just had a thought. you could probably get the tail of some small bipedal (hyspliseodon is a good example) scrape the meet off, grill it, chop it up, and put it in a salad.